# Nesting CSS declarations, is it possible and correct?

Tags: html, css, nested, css-selectors

May I nest declarations inside another selector?

```css
td:hover
{
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  border-color: purple;
  text-decoration: underline double;
  img
    {
      border: solid 2.5px purple;
    }
}
```

Is it valid and correct by using CSS?

Comment: Yes, [if you use the right browser](https://caniuse.com/css-nesting)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can nest CSS declarations within other selectors as a core part of CSS techniques. It's q way to create more specific styling rules that are applied only in certain contexts.

With `td:hover` the outer selector targets table cells () when the user hovers over them. With the nested styles, the styles within the curly braces ({ }) will be applied only to  elements that are within the hovered table cell ().

Be good to spend some more time digging into the mozilla docs for more examples and experiments.